# Loop only running once: while and for (c)

Tags: c

```
void abScores()
{
int i, choice, abScore[6], abScoreTwo[6];
char abS[6][5] = {"Str", "Dex", "Con", "Int", "Wis", "Cha"};
FILE *fp;
FILE *fo;
fp = fopen("csheet.txt", "a");

printf("Would you like your own ability scores, or the basic ability scores?\n");
printf("1 for own, 2 for basic\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

if (choice == 1)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        abScore[i] = roll();
        printf("Ability score %d: %d\n", i+1, abScore[i]);
    }
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
    abScore[0] = 15;
    abScore[1] = 14;
    abScore[2] = 13;
    abScore[3] = 12;
    abScore[4] = 10;
    abScore[5] = 8;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("Ability score %d: %d\n", i+1, abScore[i]);
}

i = 0;
while (i < 6)
{
    printf("What score would you like for %s?\nPlease use each score only once.\n", abS[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d\n", abScore[i]);
    }
    //scanf("%d", &abScoreTwo[i]);
    i++;
}

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    fprintf(fp, "%s: %d\n", abS[i], abScoreTwo[i]);
}
```

This loop only seems to run once when run in the main function. I've also tried running it as a for loop, but it only runs once. Could anyone tell me why this is happening? The function is supposed to take input from a function called roll() that rolls a six-sided die to four places in an array, adds them together, gets the lowest, then subtracts the lowest from the sum, then puts it into an array in the abScores() function. It only runs once, but I want it to run six times for the function to actually work.

Comment: Use a debugger. You're using the *same* loop variable in the for loop; when the for exits, the value is 6, and then it is incremented again and is 7 at the bottom of the first while iteration.

Comment: Your `while` loop is using the same iterator `i`. It's better to declare a new one for each loop.

Comment: The same function, only now, it's printing complete gibberish in the actual file, but in PuTTY, it will print 0's in the file for the abScoreTwo[i] values.

Answer (score 6):

you're reusing `i` in both your loops:

```
while (i < 6)
{
    printf("What score would you like for %s?\nPlease use each score only once.\n", abS[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
```

the inner `for` loop changes the value of `i` for the outer `while` loop as well and it exits at first iteration. Consider using 2 separate variables

Answer (score 2):

You re-use `i` inside the `for` loop in the while loop. After the for loop is done, `i` will be set to 6, therefore breaking your loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable in the inner loop, this is good practice, for example (changed `i` to `j`):

```
while (i < 6)
{
    printf("What score would you like for %s?\nPlease use each score only once.\n", abS[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("%2d\n", abScore[j]);
    }
    //scanf("%d", &abScoreTwo[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Another good practice would be to give more meaningful names to your variables instead of `i` and `j`